# One-sided UMP for difference in means (two-sample normal)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics

> Let $X_1,\ldots, X_m$ and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ be independent samples
>       from $N(\xi,1)$ and $N(\eta,1)$ and consider the hypothesis $H:\eta\leq\xi$
>       against $K:\eta > \xi$. There exists a UMP test, and it rejects the 
>   hypothesis
>       when $\overline{Y}-\overline{X}$ is too large.
>   [Hint: If $\xi_1 < \eta_1$ is a particular alternative, the distribution assigning probability 1 to the point $\eta=\xi=(m\xi_1 + n\eta_1)/(m+n)$ is least favorable.]

(Problem 3.61 from Lehmann/Romano 3rd ed.)

Can we just use the fact that $\overline{Y}-\overline{X} \sim N(\eta-\xi, 1/m + 1/n)$
has monotone likelihood ratio to conclude that a UMP exists?

I also tried using the suggested approach. Fixing an alternative $\xi_1<\eta_1$ and letting $\Lambda$ be the point mass at $\theta:= (m\xi_1 + n\eta_1)/(m+n)$, the NP lemma implies that the MP test for $H_0:(\xi,\eta)=(\theta,\theta)$ against
$H_1:(\xi,\eta)=(\xi_1, \eta_1)$ rejects for large values of
\begin{align*}
L = \frac{f_1}{f_0}&= \frac{N(\eta_1 - \xi_1, 1/m+1/n)}{N(0, 1/m+1/n)} \\
&=\exp\left\{ - \frac{-2(\overline{Y}-\overline{X})(\eta_1-\xi_1) + (\eta_1-\xi_1)^2}{2\cdot (1/m+1/n)}\right\}
\end{align*}
or, equivalently, if $\overline{Y}-\overline{X} > c$ for some $c$.
Then
$$
\alpha = P_0(\overline{Y}-\overline{X} > c)
= P_0\left(\frac{\overline{Y}-\overline{X} - 0}{1/m+1/n} > c\right)
\implies c = z_{1-\alpha}
$$
so that the test rejects if $\overline{Y}-\overline{X} > z_{1-\alpha}(1/m+1/n)$.
So now we just need to check that the level of the test is $\alpha$ for the original hypothesis $H:\eta\leq\xi$.

But I do not think this is correct since we did not make use of the particular choice
of $\eta=\xi=(m\xi_1 + n\eta_1)/(m+n)$?

Why do they suggest this choice (why not just pick $\eta=\xi=(\eta_1+\xi_1)/2$ for example?)